# '80s novella about a computer running everything, which is destroyed by a punch card

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence, computers, novella

I have been trying to find even a reference to this book and haven't been able to do so. I read it in the early '80s, but it might have been published a bit earlier. It was a rather small mass market paperback novella, maybe about 100 pages, with a black cover. I think the title was in green-screen letters.

What I remember of the story was that someone was bringing this computer online to run the entire country (more or less) and I *think* it was becoming self-aware. But there was a sub-plot about a suburban woman frustrated with something like an electric bill, who got a punch card she had to do something with and return. The card had the old *"Do not fold, spindle, or mutilate"* warning. So in annoyance, she carefully washed and ironed it dry, shrinking it by like 1/16", and in the end, it caused the card reader to jam and brought down the entire system.

I was quite sure the title was *"Ultima One"*, but there is no search I've tried that brings up anything relevant.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is [*Ultima One*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?52679) by Richard P. Stoughton.

Per [this](http://www.dondammassa.com/ck_sfs.htm) brief review;

> A complex computer network gets out of control and endangers the
> world.

[image]

Note that this is a 1980 novella (191 pages) with a black cover with green screen letters.

Comment: That is EXACTLY it, thank you! Now I know I'm not crazy!

Comment: @Random - [Happy to help](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)

Comment: So is there any connection between this novella and the computer game series Ultima? The third instalment in the game series, Ultima III: Exodus (1983), culminates with you destroying the titular supercomputer Exodus by feeding punch cards into it.